# What is the transmittance function of a photo filter?

Tags: optics, visible-light

The effect of some photo filters can be summarized in transmission curves such as this one:

[image: http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/lightandcolor/colortemperatureintro.html]

I do not understand which physical value is modified by the value labeled as "Diffuse Density" in the picture above. It sometimes appear as a percentage, or a ratio included between 0 and 1.

*Note: I originally posted a related question on [photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45780/23075)*

Comment: Hi wil, this is an interesting question but off-topic here.  Photography.SE is the right place for the image / color aspects of what you want.

Comment: I edited the question to include only the aspect related to optics. Tell me if it's still off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is captured in Red,Green,Blue and you know the correction filter's transmission in each of these bands you can simply scale the RGB output to give you the colour shift you want.

All you need to know is the Red,Green,Blue bandpass of the Bayer filter on your camera's chip.

You probably need to do this with your camera's raw mode. Other modes will mix some of the colours to match the response of your eye or various pre-defined coliurspaces.

Comment: I don't have an actual camera, I want to simulate the image transformation on a image stored in my computer. Do you know if the values of the parameters you're referring to are publicly available for camera chips? For a single RGB value (for example [128, 128, 255]), where do I read the scaling factor in above chart?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information adapted from the definitions found in [Schott's 2013 Optical filters Catalog](http://www.schott.com/advanced_optics/english/download/schott_optical_filters_2013_catalog_complete_en.pdf#page=16):

> [For all the wavelengths of the visible spectrum,] The spectral transmittance is the ratio of the transmitted [exiting] (energetic) spectral flux to the incident [incoming] (energetic) spectral flux. [of the illumination seen through the filter]